# variable in bat file not being read

Tags: batch-file, variables, cmd, parameters

I have a .bat file which contains the following command:

```
set /p Param=<foo.ext
START "test" /wait "C:\Program Files\blabla\bla.exe" -flag1 -flag2 %Param%
```

Param is the file to be opened by bla.exe. When I run the .bat, bla.exe opens, but it doesn't open %Param%. 
It looks like CMD only passes the string "%Param%" to bla.exe. Can I force it to pass the variable somehow?

Comment: Obviously the first line isn't working.

Comment: Is that the entire script, or is the snippet you posted inside of parentheses and you forgot to use delayed expansion?

Comment: @Noodles, I have changed all the file names and extensions.

Comment: @SomethingDark This is just a snippet and it's not within parenthesis in the whole script.

Comment: If you put `echo *%param%*` after the first line, what is the output? (The asterisks are there so that you see something even if `%param%` is empty.)

Comment: @SomethingDark I get:

Comment: @SomethingDark`*{'Binary': ☻', 'ClassName': 'STAR', 'StatePosition': 176667L, 'Version': 2}`

Comment: Your question says that param is supposed to contain a file path. That certainly doesn't look like one. Also, I wonder where the trailing asterisk went.

Comment: @SomethingDark Param is the name.fileExtension of a file located in the working directory of the bla.exe application. I'll try putting the full path in Param.

Comment: @SomethingDark full path doesn't help, I get the same output for %param%

Comment: Ohhhh, you think that the first line sets the value of Param to `foo.ext`. Because of the `<`, you're actually setting Param to _the first line_ of foo.ext, which is why your output looks like that. Get rid of the `<`.

Comment: ... and get rid of the `/p`

Comment: @ SomethingDark I got rid of  `<` and  `/p` and it works great. Thanks!

Comment: @ Magoo I got rid of  `<` and  `/p` and it works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer is:

```
set Param=foo.ext
START "test" /wait "C:\Program Files\blabla\bla.exe" -flag1 -flag2 %Param%
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to not to use %param%, just put the wanted value in its place